# Typescript 1.5 modules import export errors

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript1.5

I am having a problem re-exporting in my **typescript** project

I have class Layer and I declare it like so:

```
// Layer.ts  
export default class Layer{//code}
```

And I have another file to re-export all related files

```
// layers.ts
export Layer from "./Layer";
```

On compilation I get the following errors:

```
src/layer/layers.ts(1,14): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/layer/layers.ts(1,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/layer/layers.ts(2,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
src/layer/layers.ts(2,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/layer/layers.ts(2,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

Also another related error:
When declaring an interface with the export keyword like so:

```
export default interface MyInterface<V>{
    method():V;
}
```

I get this error again:

```
MyInterface.ts(1,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part:
`export { default as Layer} from './Layer';`

For the second part, an interface cannot be exported as `default` since interfaces are not represented by anything in the generated javascript code.

So get rid of the default keyword:

```
export interface MyInterface<V>{
    method():V;
}
```

importing using the ES6 module syntax could look like:

```
import { MyInterface } from './MyInterface';

class A implements MyInterface<string> {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be documented... 
Is this the ecma6 script spec or ts choice?
I would have expected `export Layer from './Layer';`
To work, since it is the default.